# Mysql join making all join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I am trying to access the database to two tables. In a store I keep a list of events that has a

```
Table Event
id, name,datei,houri, dateF,Hourf ,capacity, age ,description,image,url, local

Table Assistance
visibility, event, client
```

To access the list of events given an id I have

```
SELECT * from event where local = '1'
```

To access the number of people attending an event I have

```
SELECT count (*) as assistants FROM Assistance WHERE event = '1'
```

But to put together the two things I have

```
SELECT e. *, COUNT (a.client) AS asis FROM event e LEFT JOIN assistance to ON e.eid = a.event where e.locales = '1' GROUP BY a.evento
```

Here in the latter he takes me the events he wants and sometimes only when he has assistance.

Use mysql and all join is not available.

I tried debugging trying different options but I have not been successful. If it is necessary to make a contribution or clarification, indicate me. The numbers 1 are an example.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) .. *"Use mysql and all join is not available. "* you mean FULL JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

You are aggregating by a column in the *second* table of a `LEFT JOIN`.  This might be `NULL`.  You want to aggregate by the first table; and if you use a single column, it should be the primary key or unique.

So:

```
SELECT e.*, COUNT(a.event) AS asis  -- if you want to count matches, use a key in the ON clause
FROM event e LEFT JOIN
     assistance a
     ON e.eid = a.event 
WHERE e.locales = 1  -- looks like a number so I assume it is and removed the single quotes
GROUP BY e.eid;
```

Comment: This will return as a `INNER JOIN` instead as `e.locales = 1` should be in the `ON` clause ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . It is filtering on the first table, so it belongs in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: *"It is filtering on the first table, so it belongs in the WHERE clause."* Well it's is not clear what results the topicstarter is after If the topicstarter would use locales values which are non existing he would get a result just like a `INNER JOIN` see [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gXE7PhJRfkx1C7UKBrFCYe/4)

Comment: @Fer . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

To get a count from a related table, we can do a correlated subquery in the select list

```
SELECT e.*
     , ( SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM assistance a
          WHERE a.event = e.eid
       ) AS asis
  FROM event e
 WHERE e.locales = '1'
```

or we can do aggregation in an inline view, and then join to that

```
SELECT e.*
     , IFNULL(c.cnt,0) AS asis
  FROM event e
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT a.event
              , COUNT(1) AS cnt
           FROM assistance a
          GROUP
             BY a.event
       ) c
    ON c.event = e.eid
 WHERE e.locales = '1'
```

---

The specification (i.e. what the query is supposed to return) isn't clear from the question, with only the broken SQL to go by, we're just guessing at the specification.